# Fire-base stuck and not connecting with android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

HI i'm beginner android developer.I'm using Fire-base in my project but it's not connecting and stuck on **Launching Web Connect flow**....Please Help....it works fine with manual connection ...but tool isn't working.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Answer (score 5):

This problem arises when you don't have any project on Firebase. You can resolve this issue by following the points below.

1. Make sure that you are logged in with the same Google account on Android Studio and Firebase. On Firebase home page, click on **Go to console** *(present on the upper right corner).* After that a page will appear.
2. Click on **Create a project.**
3. Follow the commands coming on the way.
4. Check all the boxes to allow different permissions required to setup the project.
5. Click on **Create project.**
6. Open Android Studio *(already running in mentioned state)*.
7. After 1-5 seconds the issue will be resolved.

Well done. You solved the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me also, and I resolved it with these steps:

1. Go to the browser window that opened for Firebase.
2. Click button called "Create a project"
3. Named the new project in the Firebase site and nothing happened in my Android Studio.
4. Closed the browser and clicked cancel in Android Studio.
5. Started the process over in Android Studio, then when Firebase website opened, I clicked on the project I'd made in step #3.
6. Then the browser redirected and said "Your Android Studio project is connected to your Firebase Android app"
7. ...and the "Launching Web Connect flow" went away and it now shows as connected!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing this, Firebase Assistant plugin is incompatible with Android Studio 4.1, so you'll have to connect your project with Firebase manually by creating a new Firebase project and copying over the google-services.json

Answer (score 0):

Once you click on connect to firebase, then you will be redirected to the firebase page.
If you already have the project created in the firebase website and want to use the same then simply click on the existing project or else create a new project.
Once you are inside that project, you will get a window as [image]
Then simply click on connect and your android studio project will be connected with the firebase project.